# How to create directories in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, directory, mkdir

I am trying to create multiple directories in c++.

Here is what I am doing:

```
string folder="SYSTEM/app";
string patchFolder="D:/cpp/prototype/New_delta/patch/" + folder;
string mkdirCommand="mkdir " + patchFolder;
system(mkdirCommand.c_str());
```

But its giving: The syntax of command is incorrect.

*path up to **prototype** exists and it has to create multiple folder(New_delta, patch etc.) if not exist already.*

What is wrong with this and how to correct it? please.

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried it on the command line? You'll get the same result. Nothing to do with C++ there. Of course there's always `CreateDirectory` on Windows to do it without relying on `system`.

Comment: Yaa! the same result.

Comment: I haven't use Windows in some time, but wrong separator? Shouldn't you use `\\\`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Boost library. Check out [3rd answer here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/85516/)

Comment: You can download Boost Library http://www.boost.org/ and include it into your code.

Comment: resolved the issue using CreateDirectory() function recursively. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use _mkdir or mkdir (but you will get warnings if you use mkdir)

```
#include <direct.h>
...
_mkdir(patchFolder.c_str());
```